# Collate 2 query from a db to a single class to send it to my view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My goal is:

1. I make a call to the DB which returns to me the list of all my events.
2. I make a second call to the db which returns to me the list of all my sub-events.
3. I have an EventViewModel class that contains a List <_EventsLines> class and a List <_SubEventsLines> class.
4. I need to send the result of these 2 query in a single view but i dont know how could i do that!

I connect to a DB Filemaker and it is based on a single view, that's why I have to make 2 calls.

But then I would like to put the results of these 2 calls in the same object (oEventViewModel) in order to send them back to my view.

Would you have a solution?

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new Models.EventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    Models.EventViewModel oEventViewModel = new Models.EventViewModel
    {
        _EventsLines = (from o in results select o).ToList()
    };

    var xtoFind = new Models.SubEventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var xresults = await client.FindAsync(xtoFind);

    Models.EventViewModel oSubEventViewModel = new Models.EventViewModel
    {
        _SubEventsLines = (from x in xresults select x).ToList()
    };


    ViewBag.Zkf_CTC = 1053;
    ViewBag.JsonList = oEventViewModel;

    return View(oEventViewModel);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public List<EventsLines> _EventsLines { get; set; }
    public List<SubEventsLines> _SubEventsLines { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution ? Why do you think it is not the best ?

Comment: Because i can only return one object and from now i have 2 objects (oEventViewModel and oSubEventViewModel). I'd like to have only one object of EventViewModel who contain all my _EventsLines and all my _SubEventsLines